# Different ways to implement security using spring security framework

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring security framework.I was just compiling the various ways to add security features using spring security annotations or spring security framework.

Found the below so far.

1. Full Page Authorization 
   example: `<intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />`
2. In-Page Authorization

   example : `<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">`
3. Method Level Authorization - `@PreAuthorize,@PostAuthorize,@PreFilter,@PostFilter`

I am not sure if this is an exhaustive list to secure the application. Need some help for the same. Thanks.

Also,I am looking for security features which can easily be implemented and configurable- where developers are less likely to make mistakes and at the same time achieve the required security goals.It looks like annotations are easy to use and less ambiguous. Are annotations used only for method level authorization? Does spring security provide annotations which can be used for securing other parts of the application and can these annotations be passed parameters to configure the permissions or privileges?

I hope my question is not too broad. Any edits or helpful comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to start by identifying the requirements of your domain model, what is deemed sensitive data and what not and how this data is being accessed (HTML/JSP vs REST/JSON vs direct Java calls). Then use the authorization features as needed. Your list contains pretty much what most applications will ever need, but for finer and more advanced authorization mechanisms have a look at Spring's ACL:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html

Another important question you may want to answer to yourself is which application layer will be responsible for enforcing your security: MVC/REST vs Services (scattering this concern across multiple layers is usually bad idea). This will directly dictate the choices of SS features you are going to make.

You may wish to build your own annotations on top of SS annotations which reflect closely your particular domain. This way all complexity will be concentrated in a single place, leaving less room for error.

For example, you can create a custom annotation such as `@AuthorizedFor` where you can add various domain-specific parameters. You then annotate this annotation with one of SS annotations, say `@Pre/PostAuthorize("hasAnyRole()")` (here you can also play with the Spring's native EL to further customise the behaviour) and use custom implementation of `Pre/PostInvocationAuthorizationAdvice` where you make the authorization decisions based on your custom annotation parameters. The added advantage here is that you will be able to secure complete classes with your custom annotation instead of having to annotate all methods in that class. In your implementation you get the `MethodInvocation` instance from where you can interrogate the class containing the method and see if its annotated, then proceed as-if the method itself was annotated.

See this article for more in-depth discussion: http://blog.novoj.net/2012/03/27/combining-custom-annotations-for-securing-methods-with-spring-security/

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for security features which can easily be implemented and configurable- where developers are less likely to make mistakes and at the same time achieve the required security goals.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 ways to implement spring security. through bean configuration in .xml files and other by using Annotations. Annotation based method is easy to use in long term as it is less ambiguous.

here is the reference to spring.io . Both ways are explained nicely.

http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

Annotation is pure java based configuration and will most probably overtake xml configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Annotations look interesting to me . Are there annotations which are configurable? For example, I provided the method level security annotations where you provide the parameters - like the roles of users who have the privileges to access the method or to access the elements returned by the method .

Comment: These are basically layers of security. For me i start by securing the url's for different roles, as grid explained method level security is second level security and more secure. These layers works together fine as long as  they are not contradicted by each other, rendering the method to be unreachable.   http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/preauthorize-postauthorize-in-spring-security      method level security simple example.

Answer (score 1):

The three items in your list serve different purposes:

1. intercept-url :  Adds security at the servlet layer. In other words, you control who can/cannot access any url in your application.  For example you may add permission only to administrators to access the url `/admin/some_critical_operation`, but allow all authenticated users to access `/some_informational_page`. It is possible to secure your application with this type of authorisation only but it is very fragile design. Adding or changing urls can easily break security without notice.
2. In-Page Authorization:  It is not real authorisation, just a convenience tag for hiding html content not intended for the current user. For example a non-admin user should not see the button `create new user`. As I said it is not real security measure since the user can type the url in the browser and gain access if none of the other authorisation types have been applied.
3. Method Level Authorization: Adds security to the service layer.  This means you can apply restrictions on who can/cannot call a method of some service class. It is considered more secure and harder to compromise since it is applied deeper in the application layer stack.  It can be applied both with annotations and with the security namespace.

Usually you start by securing your application in the service layer and then add some url control as well.  Adding authorisation tags in pages is optional.

Comment: Thanks. So w.r.t spring security annotations, I have mentioned some for method level authorization. Does spring security provide annotations which can be used at other places apart from method level authorization?

Comment: there are no respective annotations to secure urls if you mean this afaik. In some way you could hack into this by annotating controller methods but it is not recommended since there are several problems (see http://www.javatronic.fr/articles/2014/03/15/method_level_security_with_spring_security_and_spring_mvc.html ). On the other hand, you can avoid xml by applying java config. see this example in spring reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but regarding your question:

*Are there annotations which are configurable? For example, I provided the method level security annotations where you provide the parameters - like the roles of users who have the privileges to access the method or to access the elements returned by the method*

You are free to write your own annotations, which are in turn annotated with the native Spring Security annotations. This makes them essentially a domain-specific extension. That said, the standard SS annotations allow the use of [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) which is rather flexible even tough is not bound to your particular domain. You can easily assert if user has certain roles (GrantedAuthority), etc ...

If you want to implement your own annotations, see the link in my other answer for a thorough discussion.

I can give you a concrete example from a recent project I worked on. We had authorization groups managed by external system and also built-in logic which defines access to certain resources. So, essentially we had 2 places to look for authorization parameters. We've created the concept of Authorization Groups (retrieved externally via LDAP) and Authorization Roles (built-in, business logic). The groups were simple - if user is a member of the group, they are granted access, else denied. With the roles, we had business rules which determine whether the user has a particular role or not (for example - signed T&C, accepted EULA, etc ...). All of these are determined at the authentication stage.

To make it easier to reason about our access control, we created two annotations  `@AuthorisedForGroups({group1, group2, ...})` and `@AuthorisedForRoles({role1, role2,...})`. Each of these was in turn annotated with Spring's native `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole()")`. Note the use of "hasAnyRole()" - this is simply to tell Spring "let everybody who is authenticated in" and that "we are going to make the authorization decisions ourselves". The authorization decisions are then made in a custom implementation of `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice` (in fact we just extended Spring's own implementation `ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice`) and put the decision-making logic in `#before()` method:

```
    @Override
    public boolean before(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation mi, PreInvocationAttribute attr) {
        // 1) get AuthorisedForGroups & AuthorisedForRoles for the method
        // 2) if either is missing from the method, check the enclosing class 
        // 3) if no annotations found - simply return super.before(...) 
        // 4) else, introspect the 'authentication' and see if it has the required groups/roles 
        // - here you may want to use 'ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory' to 
        //   create your own expressions which you then pass to super.before(...). 
        //   This especially makes sense when your groups/roles 
        //   are mapped to GrantedAuthority instances - as it was the case with our code. 


    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can yuo explain how my custom annotations become domain specific? I didnt understand the domain term here. What domain are we referring to?

Comment: By "domain" I mean your particular **business domain**. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_domain & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_model. In your context, it means you create annotations which are tailored to solving the problems of your business model. When well designed, this approach will result in concentrating the complexity in a single place while making the rest of the code more readable and easier to reason about.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to understand the domain term in context of the annotations that we are talking about. I appreciate you answer. But I think it would be great if you would give an example of annotation usage which are tailored to solve problems in a business model. Most of these annotations that I have encountered so far check for existence of roles or privileges, which are defined by the business requirements.

Comment: Just expanded the answer above with an example from a recent project of mine